# function inside dictionary with parameters

Tags: python

i am wondering if parameters can be passed in a function within a dictionary, like

```
mydict = { 'a' : afunc(myparam) }
```

In my code below, I am following the instructions of someone who wanted to help, but the code did not get me where I need to be.

Here is my current code, fwiw

```
signals = {
    u'leave_game': leave_game,
    u'generate_first_4_problems_game': (generate_first_4_problems_game, (level, operation)),
    u'generate_problem_game': (generate_problem_game, (level, opertaion)),
}
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Are you trying to store some data to use later as arguments to the function?

Comment: Should the value of `level` and `operation` be determined ahead of time, or only when the command is looked up in the dictionary?

Comment: I'm trying to execute the generate_first_4_problems_game() function with the parameters `level` and `operation`. This should be done when I do signals['generate_first_4_problems_game']

Comment: Where are the values of `level` and `operation` coming from? Are these known before the dict is created?

Comment: yes, these are known before the dict is created

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

signals = {
    u'leave_game': partial(leave_game)
    u'generate_first_4_problems_game': partial(generate_first_4_problems_game, level, operation),
    u'generate_problem_game': partial(generate_problem_game, level, operation),
}
```

Now each value is a callable object which, when called with no additional arguments, calls your function with the stored arguments.

```
signals['generate_problem_game']()  # equivalent to generate_problem_game(level, operation)
```

Comment: `lambda: generate_first_4_problems_game(level, operation)` is arguably more readable than using `partial`, but captures `level` by name rather than by value

Comment: There's also the issue of whether you want to restrict `signals[whatever]` to the arguments used in building the dict (as `lambda` would do), or allow additional or overriden arguments (as `partial` allows).

Comment: Moral of the story: there are reasons to use each; for this answer, though, I chose the one that doesn't make the function dependent on the call-time environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```py
mydict = {
    'a': (afunc, (myparam,))
}

f, params = mydict['a']
f(*params)
```